# Run batch file from another folder

Tags: windows, batch

The Folder that contains the batch file and the folder that contains the audio files that will be normalized are on the Desktop.

When I move the folder containing the batch file to another location, eg D:\ and run the batch file, it says that it has not found the audio file that is in the folder on the desktop.

The batch cancels when it executes the FOR command that will read the audio file in the desktop folder:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.flac ^|find /v /i "_LOUDNORM" ^|find /v /i "_EBU"') DO
```

I tried to change the FOR command putting the absolute path of the desktop folder, according to the information in the link below, but even so the command does not find the file:

[command-prompt-dir-b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206088/command-prompt-dir-b-s-file-txt-need-to-remove-directories-from-results)

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Audios to convert\*.flac ^|find /v /i "_LOUDNORM" ^|find /v /i "_EBU"') DO
```

or

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Audios to convert\*.flac" ^|find /v /i "_LOUDNORM" ^|find /v /i "_EBU"') DO
```

How to make the batch file work correctly being run in the directory D:\ ?

Full command:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.flac ^|find /v /i "_LOUDNORM" ^|find /v /i "_EBU"') DO (
  SET "filename=%%~na"   
  ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "%%a" -af "[0:a]loudnorm=print_format=summary" -f null NUL 2> "%%~na.log"
  @FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Input Integrated" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET II=%%b)
  @FOR /F "tokens=4" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Input True Peak" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET ITP=%%b)
  @FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Input LRA" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET ILRA=%%b)
  @FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Input Threshold" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET IT=%%b)
  @FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Target Offset" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET TO=%%b)
  DEL "%%~na.log"
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  ECHO !II!   Input Integrated
  ECHO !ITP!  Input True Peak
  ECHO !ILRA! Input LRA
  ECHO !IT!   Input Threshold
  ECHO !TO!   Target Offset
  FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%b IN ('ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams a -show_entries "stream=sample_fmt,sample_rate" -of "csv=p=0" "!filename!.flac"') DO (
  ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "!filename!.flac" -af "loudnorm=linear=true:I=!_vLUF!:LRA=11:tp=!_vPEAK!:measured_I=!II!:measured_LRA=!ILRA!:measured_tp=!ITP!:measured_thresh=!IT!:offset=!TO!:print_format=summary" -c:v copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" -map 0:0 -c:a flac -sample_fmt:a %%b -ar:a %%c "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Normalizando_lufs\!filename!.flac"
  )
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

Comment: What comes after the do part I think the error is there...

Comment: @Ricardo Bohner I put the full command in my question.

Comment: It seems like you only refeer to the "filename" in you command but if you are not in the same folder as the file you have to put the full path or relative path to the file. Or you go to the path where the files are like @itwasntme suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
@echo off

pushd "%Userprofile%\Desktop\Audios to convert"
for /f delimsˆ= %%a in ('where .:*.flac ^|findstr /vi "_loudnorm  _ebu"')do ...
popd
```

Comment: is `popd` part of the command?

Comment: [yes, `pushd folder\path` ... after you don't need it anymore, run `popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)

Comment: @ifwasntme but it is not necessary since the bat file ends there anyway right?

Comment: yes, probably yes

Comment: `pushd` and `popd` are your friends.  You are lucky that @iTwasnTme pointed you to them.  You actually didn't need them (there are so many other ways) but I too would have chosen this ***path*** (stupid geek pun intended).

Comment: @iTwasnTme it worked... show, thanks!

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas 
IoI gracias mi Señor

Comment: @Clamarc Show the las Pelotas

Comment: @iTwasnTme e la Pelota... este ano no Catar, vai ser do Brasil!...kkkk