# Run two executables after one another from different locations in batch file, with spaces in a filename and pass commands to the other

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, script

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\"
start "World of Warcraft Launcher" "World of Warcraft Launcher.exe"
cd "C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit\" 
start obs64.exe --startstreaming --minimize-to-tray
exit
```

This doesn't work, but I've been looking through 10+ threads on here about running files in batch scripts, I actually got it working at one point and then deleted the wrong file.

I can (I forget now I've been trying every variation I can find) get WoW to run, but when obs runs I get an error about missing library files or something. Can't remember how I had it to get to those points but like I say I did eventually get it working and now i've lost it again.. most questions like this only talk about spaces in the directory tree and not the filename and the ones that do either don't work (eg start "" "program name.exe") etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I get an error about missing library files or something` Exact error messages go a long way in helping to troubleshoot the issue.  And what does `This doesn't work...` mean?  Throws an error?  Nothing happens?  Not the expected result?

Comment: I can't get it again because I don't remember the script setup I used to get to that point, my thinking is that it is something to do with it trying to run it out of the parent directory or something like that. Right now that script won't even launch WoW (should it work?) (Says cannot find the exe)

Answer (score 0):

You can try  [`pushd`](https://superuser.com/a/1722239/969781):

```
@echo off

cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\"
start "World of Warcraft Launcher" /b "World of Warcraft Launcher.exe"

pushd "C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit\" 
start "" /b obs64.exe --startstreaming --minimize-to-tray
exit
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get notified of any more responses.

https://i.imgur.com/Pa7dFbo.png

>@echo off

>cd /d "E:\Games\Heroes of the Storm\Support64"
>start "Heroes of the Storm" /b "HeroesSwitcher_x64.exe"

>pushd "C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit" 
>start “” /b obs64.exe --startstreaming --minimize-to-tray
>exit

Answer (score 0):

Sorry friends I just forgot all about this because I stopped gett

Trying this now:
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

`cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\"` doesn't actually switch to that directory unless you're already on c:.

Because "cd" switches the current directory on a given drive, but does not switch drives (in Windows/MSDOS each drive has it's own "current directory").

You have to to something like:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\"
c:
start "World of Warcraft Launcher" "World of Warcraft Launcher.exe"
```

(note line with "c:")

Of course it could be something else (if you are already on c:). Post the error messages you get.

Also - the first rule of batch file debugging is to run the steps by hand one at a time. If they don't work that way, they certainly won't work in the batch file.

Comment: Actually, `cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft\"` is the only line needed here before calling start.  It can also be included in the start command making this a one liner.. as in `start "World of Warcraft Launcher" /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft" "World of Warcraft Launcher.exe"` .. look at `start /?` or `cd /?` and you will see the options.

Comment: Got it working like this thanks guys.
`@echo off
start "World of Warcraft Launcher" /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\World of Warcraft" "World of Warcraft Launcher.exe"
start "" /d "C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit\" "obs64.exe" --startstreaming --minimize-to-tray
exit`

Comment: If you update the answer with the information OP showed success with, I will upvote it.